# How to make an html dropdown work with PHP post?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I just modified my php file switching from a text box from one of my fields to a dropdown list and it no longer returns the "sexo" field in the output. Can someone tell me why this is? All I did was switch from a text box to a list. 
It won't return all of the results it will only return the values from all columns except the sexo column which should be either Masculino or Femenino

The error I'm guessing has to be in the form or in the POST variable for "sexo"

```
    <?php
include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';
include_once 'includes/functions.php';

sec_session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
   header("Location: index.php");
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="datepicker.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="demo.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ValidarDatos.js"></script>


<title>Consulta niño Coprodeli Intranet</title>
</head>
<body>


<div id="content">
    <div id="logo"> <a href="#"> <img src="images/logo.jpg" /></a> </div>
    <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="ConsultaNino.php" class="seleccionado">Niños</a></li>
            <li><a href="ConsultaPadrino.php">Padrinos</a></li>
            <li><a href="ConsultaCentro.php">Centros</a></li>
            <li><a href="Informes.php">Informes</a></li>            
            <li><a href="ConsultaUsuario.php">Usuarios</a></li>         
            <li><a href="Security/aut_logout.php">Salir</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="intro2">
        <h1>Intranet Coprodeli</h1>
        <p>Apadrinamiento y Programa<br />
            de Niños en Alto Riesgo</p>
        <div id="login">
            </div>
    </div>
    <div id="right2">
    <h4 class="migas">Estás en: <a href="home.php">Inicio</a> | Consulta de niños</h4>
    <br />


<?php
$output = NULL;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    // Connect to the database
    $mysqli = NEW MySQLi("localhost","root","","coprodeli");
    $nino_id = $mysqli->real_escape_string( $_POST['nino_id']);
    $nombre = $mysqli->real_escape_string( $_POST['nombre']);
    $apellidos = $mysqli->real_escape_string( $_POST['apellidos']);
    $sexo = $mysqli->real_escape_string( $_POST['sexo']);
    $estado = $mysqli->real_escape_string( $_POST['estado']);
    $fecha_de_nacimiento_desde = $mysqli->real_escape_string( $_POST['fecha_de_nacimiento_desde']);
    $fecha_de_nacimiento_hasta = $mysqli->real_escape_string( $_POST['fecha_de_nacimiento_hasta']);
    $tipo_de_centro = $mysqli->real_escape_string( $_POST['tipo_de_centro']);
    $nombre_del_centro = $mysqli->real_escape_string( $_POST['nombre_del_centro']);
    $region_del_centro = $mysqli->real_escape_string( $_POST['region_del_centro']);
    $nivel_de_estudio = $mysqli->real_escape_string( $_POST['nivel_de_estudio']);
    $entrada_desde = $mysqli->real_escape_string( $_POST['entrada_desde']);
    $entrada_hasta = $mysqli->real_escape_string( $_POST['entrada_hasta']);
    $egreso_desde = $mysqli->real_escape_string( $_POST['egreso_desde']);
    $egreso_hasta = $mysqli->real_escape_string( $_POST['egreso_hasta']);



    //Query the database
    $resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT nino_id, nombre, apellidos, sexo, estado, fecha_de_nacimiento_desde, fecha_de_nacimiento_hasta,
    tipo_de_centro, nombre_del_centro, region_del_centro, nivel_de_estudio, entrada_desde, entrada_hasta, egreso_desde, egreso_hasta FROM nino
    WHERE nino_id = '$nino_id' AND nombre = '$nombre' AND apellidos = '$apellidos' AND sexo = '$sexo' AND estado = '$estado' AND fecha_de_nacimiento_desde = '$fecha_de_nacimiento_desde'
    AND fecha_de_nacimiento_hasta = '$fecha_de_nacimiento_hasta' AND tipo_de_centro = '$tipo_de_centro' AND nombre_del_centro = '$nombre_del_centro' AND
    region_del_centro = '$region_del_centro' AND nivel_de_estudio = '$nivel_de_estudio' AND entrada_desde = '$entrada_desde' AND entrada_hasta = '$entrada_hasta'
  AND egreso_desde = '$egreso_desde' AND egreso_hasta = '$egreso_hasta';" ) ;
    // Edited on 9/7/2015 12:39PM by Anthony Sawah. I changed it from  "  if($resultSet['num_rows'] > 0) {   "  to " if($resultSet->num_rows > 0) {"
    if($resultSet->num_rows > 0) {
        while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $nino_id = $rows['nino_id'];
            $nombre = $rows['nombre'];
            $apellidos = $rows['apellidos'];
            $sexo = $rows['sexo'];
            $estado = $rows['estado'];
            $fecha_de_nacimiento_desde = $rows['fecha_de_nacimiento_desde'];
            $fecha_de_nacimiento_hasta = $rows['fecha_de_nacimiento_hasta'];
            $tipo_de_centro = $rows['tipo_de_centro'];
            $nombre_del_centro = $rows['nombre_del_centro'];
            $region_del_centro = $rows['region_del_centro'];
            $nivel_de_estudio = $rows['nivel_de_estudio'];
            $entrada_desde = $rows['entrada_desde'];
            $entrada_hasta = $rows['entrada_hasta'];
            $egreso_desde = $rows['egreso_desde'];
            $egreso_hasta = $rows['egreso_hasta'];
            $output .=              "<tr><td>".$estado."</td><td>".$nino_id."</td><td>".$apellidos."</td><td>".$nombre."</td><td>".$egreso_desde."</td><td>".$egreso_hasta."</td>";
        }
    }else{
        $output = "No results";
    }
}
?>
<fieldset class="required">
        <legend>Consulta de niños:</legend>
    <form method ="POST">
        <p>ID niño: <input type="text" name="nino_id" />
          <br> </br>
          Nombre: <input type="text" name="nombre" />
          <br> </br>
          Apellidos: <input type="text" name="apellidos" />  <br> </br>
        Sexo:
        <select name="sexo">
          <option value=""> Select...</option>
          <option value="Masculino">Masculino</option>
          <option value="Femenino">Femenino</option>
        </select>
        <br> 
        </br>
          Estado: <input type="text" name="estado" />  <br> </br>
          Fecha de
          nacimiento desde
          (DD-MM-YYYY): <input type="text" name="fecha_de_nacimiento_desde" />  <br> </br>
          Fecha de
          nacimiento hasta
          (DD-MM-YYYY): <input type="text" name="fecha_de_nacimiento_hasta" />  <br> </br>
          Tipo de centro: <input type="text" name="tipo_de_centro" />  <br> </br>
          Nombre Del Centro: <input type="text" name="nombre_del_centro" />  <br> </br>
          Región del Centro: <input type="text" name="region_del_centro" />  <br> </br>
          Nivel de estudio: <input type="text" name="nivel_de_estudio" />  <br> </br>
          Entrada desde
          (DD-MM-YYYY): <input type="text" name="entrada_desde" />  <br> </br>
          Entrada hasta
          (DD-MM-YYYY): <input type="text" name="entrada_hasta" />  <br> </br>
          Egreso desde
          (DD-MM-YYYY): <input type="text" name="egreso_desde" />  <br> </br>
          Egreso hasta
          (DD-MM-YYYY): <input type="text" name="egreso_hasta" />  <br> </br>


          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
        </p>
    </form>
    </fieldset>



        <fieldset id="" class="required">
        <legend>Resultado de la b&uacute;squeda:</legend>
        <form id="form7" name="ResultadoBusqueda" action="ConsultarDetalleNino.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" >
            <table>

                <tr>
                    <td class="especial" width="11"></td>
                    <td colspan="6" class="especial"> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th width="15"></th>
                    <th width="88">Estado</th>
                    <th width="104">ID ninos </th>
                    <th width="234">Apellidos</th>
                    <th width="81">Nombre</th>
                    <th width="128">Fecha Ingreso</th>
                    <th width="106">Fecha Egreso</th>
                </tr>

                <?php echo $output;?>

            </table>



        <div class="actions">
          <input name="ConsultarDetalleNino" type="submit" class="primaryAction" id="submit-" value="Consultar Detalle">



            <input name="Cancelar" type="submit" class="primaryAction" id="submit-" value="Cancelar">
        </div>

        </form>
        <form id="ListadoNinos" name="ListadoNinos" action="InformeNinos.php"  method="post" target="_blank"></form>
        </fieldset>

    <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <div id="col1">
        <p><a href="#"> </a><a href="#"></a><br />
            &copy;  <a href="#"></a></p>
    </div>
    <div id="col2">
        <p>Info:<strong><a href=""></a></strong><br />
            Info2: <strong>completar</strong></p>
    </div>
    <div id="col3">
        <p>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what are the "exact" values you used to put in that input before? Row values are case-sensitive, remember that. `Masculino` isn't the same as `masculino`. Those are two different animals altogether.

Comment: I put "Masculino" before.   Masculino

Comment: `$sexo` isn't in your echo'd `$output .=` far as I can tell so far.

Comment: You're right. LOL okay thanks.

Comment: so problem solved then?

Comment: Add your comment as an answer so I can give u answer points.

Comment: You asked me to post an answer Anthony, and I have.

Answer (score 1):

The reason being is because `$sexo` isn't included in your echo'd `$output .=` variables.

NOTA: There are other variables in your loop that are not part of the echo'd output, so make sure to add those if you want them to be echo'd also.

Comment: fred knows all about the *sexo*

Comment: @Dagon As does the "The Shadow". I guess he had to be in that kinky stuff at one point.